# retrofit2 - duplicate url parameter names issue

Tags: retrofit2

I am coding a json/rest client in java/retrofit2. Works great, run into one snag. The service I am a client of (teamdesk.net) uses duplicate url parameters to express selecting specific columns. (Without any column parameters it will just select all) .. so like this:

```
?column=firstname&column=lastname&column=age ...
```

I know I could model this by using N number of @Query() decorators eg:

```
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Query("column") String col1, @Query("column") String col2);
```

Problem here is then I am limited to a fixed N number of columns. I could make multiple request methods to handle this (1 column, 2 columns, 3 columns.. etc) but that is unwieldy.

I can't use the @QueryMap() pattern as it will not allow - for obvious reasons - multiple "column" keys.

I tried this pattern and it works:

```
@GET("Patient/select.json{query}")
Call<List<Patient>> getPatients(@Path("query") String urlquery);
```

and then calling thus:

```
getPatients("?top=5&column=firstname&column=lastname&column=age")
```

But I fear that this is hacking and that some later version of retrofit will break this.

So I am looking for suggestions:

1) Is my @GET("Patient/select.json{query}") hack a good idea ?

2) is there some better way to allow me to gain edit access to the url parameters before calling ?

3) Is there some existing interceptor pattern that can help ?

4) Could I write my own interceptor pattern for this - i'm up for it..

thanks in advance.

Comment: I should mention that it is my intention to allow a user to be able to select what columns they want to query dynamically in the UI. If that were not the case, then just having a fixed N number or columns, and knowing what columns are to be queried - is perfectly workable with the existing @Query() mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

From the retrofit [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html) you can simply use varargs with the @Query annotation, so like this:

```
@GET("Patient/select.json")
Call<List<Patient>> getPatients(@Query("column") String... columns);
```

which you can call with any number of Strings

```
getPatients("column1", ..., "columnN");
```

and will result in the url:

> yourBaseUrl/Patient/select.json?column=column1&...&column=columnN

Comment: right answer.  Missed that in the docs. thanks. sorry - cant upvote your answer - I don't have enough SO reputation yet.